# How to convert UTC to EST java.util.date in Java8+?

Tags: java, java-time

I have my code below which converts UTC to EST. But, how can I convert ZonedDateTime to java.util.Date  from the below code along with this format (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss) ?

```java
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
String f = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
String timestamp = "2022-03-01T16:29:03"; //sample input

TemporalAccessor temporalAccessor = formatter.parse(timestamp);
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.from(temporalAccessor);
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime, ZoneId.systemDefault());
Instant result = Instant.from(zonedDateTime);
ZonedDateTime nyTime = result.atZone(ZoneId.of("Canada/Eastern"));
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(f);
System.out.println("Date EST : " + format.format(nyTime));
```

Comment: @veejayD But why do you need `Date`?

Comment: @MCEmperor I need to populate this in DB column. So I need to convert a string which is in UTC to EST then converting ZonedDateTime back to java.util.Date in this format (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss)

Comment: @veejayD Never use either `Date` class. Use only *java.time* classes .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Avoid legacy classes

You commented:

> I need to populate this in DB column. So I need to convert a string which is in UTC to EST then converting ZonedDateTime back to java.util.Date in this format (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss)

Never use either `Date` class. Use only *java.time* classes. JDBC 4.2 and later supports *java.time* for exchanging date-time values with a database.

- For a column of a type akin to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, use `java.time.LocalDateTime`.
- For a column of a type akin to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, use `java.time.OffsetDateTime`.

### Not a moment

Your input string:

> `String timestamp = "2022-03-01T16:29:03";`

… is misnamed. That value lacks an indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So it cannot represent a moment. We have no way of knowing if that is around 4:30 PM in Tokyo Japan, or in Toulouse France, or in Toledo Ohio US — all very different moments several hours apart. So calling this a “timestamp” is misleading.

Parse that input string as a `LocalDateTime`. No need to specify a formatting pattern. That string complies with ISO 8691, used by default in the *java.time* classses when parsing/generating text.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2022-03-01T16:29:03" ) ;
```

## Moment

Your code at this point seems convoluted. You assign a default time zone to this date-with-time. But that seems unlikely to make sense. I am guessing that your intention was for this specific date-with-time to represent a specific moment as seen in a specific time zone.

Apparently you want eastern Canada  time zone. The [proper name for that zone](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) is `America/Toronto`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Toronto" ) ;
```

Assign that zone to produce a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

Now we have a moment, a specific point on the timeline.

### JDBC

But for writing to a database column of a type akin to the SQL-standard `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, we need to use `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = zdt.toOffsetDateTime() ;
```

Later you commented that the input string is intended to represent a moment in UTC. So assign a `ZoneOffset` object, the constant `UTC`, to get an `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Send to the database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

### Converting legacy ↔ modern

If you must use `java.util.Date` to  interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, you can convert to and fro. Look to the new `to…` and `from…` methods added to the old classes.

```
java.util.Date d = Date.from( odt.toInstant() ) ;
java.util.Date d = Date.from( zdt.toInstant() ) ;
```

Going the other direction.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

All of these topics have been addressed many times on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I am afraid that we had missed to use java.time and we have been using java.util.Date. we will take this part of debt to fix across the project. Also, it will take rounds of discussion to ask the client to send the timestamp with Zone information. But, right now it's an assumption we will receive it in UTC. Could you please help me in updating your post with how can I attain java.util.Date from the input in the desired format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"). Forget about the code snippet I tried it might be a crap because I have very little exp with Java :(.

Comment: @veejayD See my edits. Also, all this has been covered many many times on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

Once you have `ZonedDateTime` in correct time zone  convert it to Instant and then use method [public static Date from(Instant instant)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#from-java.time.Instant-) of class Date.

```
Instant instant = Instant.from(zonedDateTime);
Date date = Date.from(instant);
```

However, if you can, refrain from usage of Date class which is outdated (pun intended) package `java.time` with classes like `ZonedDateTime`, `Instant`
and others should be used